# Screen appears stretched when disabling mirroring in Unity while using the Oculus

Tags: unity-game-engine, monitor, oculus, virtual-reality

I am making a game that displays different content on an Oculus and another content on the main monitor. I noticed a problem when trying to disable the mirroring. Whatever is displayed on the main monitor gets stretched widely but what is displayed on the VR remains proper. I tried disabling the OVR prefab but it would still stretch as long as the "Virtual Reality Supported" check box is checked. If I uncheck it, it will still stretch if the OVR prefab is active. Trying to delay the activation will result in the OVR camera not rendering to the VR headset.

Just to be clearer. I have two cameras in the scene, one is for the VR which is the OVR prefab and the other is a standard camera (which gets stretched) with its Target Eye set to "None (Main Display)" used to display what I need to the main monitor.

Is there any solution for this?

The following code is what I used to stop the mirroring to the monitor:

```
    IEnumerator Start ()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
        UnityEngine.VR.VRSettings.showDeviceView = false;
    }
```

Also, I am using Unity 5.3.1p3 (tried earlier versions with the same result) and Oculus SDK 0.8 with a DK2.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Having engineered many Oculus games, as I understood it *"I am making a game that displays different content on an Oculus and another content on the main monitor"* - you mean at the same time? - that is simply not possible. Perhaps something has changed very recently?!

Comment: Yes at the same time and it is quite possible. There are some games that did like Eve Valkyrie. I also asked on the forums and one guy from Oculus said it is possible but did not respond to my issue. I am assuming it could be a problem from Unity's side.

Comment: Seems bizarre - I had no idea!  Cheers.